# How do I replace cartesian products when I need them to create merged nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cartesian-product

So I'm working with a program management data set that doesn't have that many records (in the low thousands), but still hangs up a lot when I'm trying to visualize multiple types of relationships. I have indexes, such as on Project ID, but I think the slowness has to do with the fact that I'm having to create a temporary set of project nodes (CREATE) in order to match different organizations to permanent project nodes (MERGE based on ProjectID). Assuming I already have organization nodes loaded, the code is as follows:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Project.csv" AS p
CREATE (:ProjectTemp {
Project_ID: toString(p.ProjectId),
Project_Name: toString(p.ProjectTitle),
Org_ID: toString(p.`Org ID`) })

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Project.csv" AS row
MERGE (p:Project {Project_ID: toString(row.ProjectId),
Project_Name: toString(row.ProjectTitle) })

MATCH (o:Organization), (pt:ProjectTemp),(p:Project) 
WHERE o.Org_ID=pt.Org_ID AND pt.Org_Role='Lead Recipient' AND 
pt.Project_ID=p.Project_ID 
MERGE (o)-[:LEAD]->(p)
```

Is there any way not to have to use the Project Temp nodes to match and avoid the problem of cartesian products? Or is there a way to make it faster/more efficient?
I need to support multiple relationships (e.g. Sub, Vendor), not just Lead. Also the reason I need the temp nodes because there are properties that some records of the same Project ID have, but not others, that determine how an organization is related to a project. Basically I want to merge on ProjectID so all relationships point to the same Project, while still maintaining properties at the individual record level to properly match organizations, but the only way I've thought of doing that so far is using temp nodes.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need :ProjectTemp? Why don't you just use `row.<prop>` in the second commit batch?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you need `ProjectTemp` nodes.

For example, if you ensured that each `Project` node existed, and that each node has a `HAS_PROJECT` relationship from the right `Organization`, like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Project.csv" AS row
MATCH (o:Organization) WHERE o.Org_ID = row.`Org ID`
MERGE (p:Project {Project_ID: row.ProjectId})
ON CREATE SET p.Project_Name = row.ProjectTitle
MERGE (o)-[:HAS_PROJECT]->(p)
```

Then your last query (to add all the `LEAD` relationships) would not even be necessary. Instead, whenever you needed to find the lead `Project`s for an `Organization`, you'd just need to do something like this:

```
MATCH (o:Organization)-[:HAS_PROJECT]->(p:Project) 
WHERE o.Org_ID = "123" AND p.Org_Role='Lead Recipient' 
...
```

To make the above efficient, you would have indexes on:

- :Organization(Org_ID)
- :Project(Project_ID)

Comment: I may be misunderstanding neo4j, but I thought that I need Project Temp because we want to show the specific relationships (LEAD), (SUB), (VENDOR), etc... so instead of a [:HAS_PROJECT] relationship, I need each of the specific ones. I'm envisioning multiple types of relationships that can go from (o)-->(p), and p.Project_ID has to be unique so that the different relationships go to the same merged project node

Comment: That important requirement (supporting multiple types of relationships) should have been specified in the Question, as it totally changes things. Nevertheless, it is still not clear that you need temp nodes -- that is very rare.

Comment: Sorry I was trying not to make the initial question too long, but it seems I didn't add enough. The reason I need the temp nodes because there are properties that some records of the same Project ID have, but not others, that determine how an organization is related to a project. Basically I want to merge on ProjectID so all relationships point to the same Project, while still maintaining properties at the individual record level to properly match organizations, but the only way I've thought of doing that so far is using temp nodes.